# Groups API empty collection

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I'm currently working on a legacy app, that is using Microsoft Graph API to retrieve groups (owners and members).

The app logs in via Oauth2, gets an access token and then uses this to call the Graph API.

The issue seems to be that I can get the owners, using the following:

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenent}/groups/{my_group}/owners?api-version=1.6
```

But the members are always coming back as an empty collection:

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenent}/groups/{my_group}/members?api-version=1.6
```

The odd thing is, that if i use the old AD Graph Explorer (https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#) and use the above URLs, I get a collection of results for both endpoints.

Is this a potential bug in the API, or are there any extra permissions that need to be set?

Both the owners (teachers) and the members (students) are being sync'd into AAD with SDS.

This happens both on my local development and in staging/production.

Thanks

EDIT:

FWIW - I'm currently using the old Graph API endpoint https://graph.windows.net

Comment: Re-tagging this question to remove Microsoft Graph related tags. The Azure AD Graph API and Microsoft Graph are distinct APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this on my side, I used app login via Oauth2, gets an access token and then used this to call the Graph API, the requests for the owners and members success.

Request for members:

[image]

Request for owners:

[image]

Comment: When you say the "app login via OAuth2" what URL are you using? My app is logging into: https://login.windows.net/{tenent}/oauth2/authorize and then I get the access code token, which I'm using as the JWT/Bearer. The difference seems to be that the token is a different length, than one i get back from

Comment: I use v1 endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?` to get the authorization_code.